# Fallo al conectarse las maquinas virtuales Kali y Windows

Tags: redes, virtualbox, conexión

he intentado conectarme dos maquinas virtuales Kali Linux y Windows , he configurado las interfaces de red y el firewall para hacer pruebas de hacking  pero a la hora de hacer un ping desde Kali Linux hasta Windows 10 no llega el ping a la maquina virtual, ademas la maquina virtual de Windows no identifica la red yo he activado el ip_forward y configurado la red NAT para que salga desde fuera hasta la red interna, pero sin resultados.

[image: Adaptadores de red Kali]
[image: Adaptadores de red Windows]
[image: Configuración de red Kali]
[image: Configuración de red Windows]
[image: Tablas de enrutamiento]
[image: Tablas ARP]
[image: Ping hacia VM Windows 10]